# SaveOrUpdate is trying to insert NULL into primary key field

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I'm creating a little application using Sharp Architecture, and I've run into a bug I can't figure out. I think it has something to do with the NHibernte mappings. In my HttpPost Create() method, my SaveOrUpdate call is trying to insert null into the table's primary key field. The declaration for the primary key in my model is `public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }`.

I checked newSprint.Id and it's zero. I think the problem's with my NHibernate Mappings, so I've included all of that below.

Here's the automapping configuration:

```
public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
    {
        public override bool ShouldMap(System.Type type)
        {
            return type.GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
                 x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>));
        }

        public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
        {
            return base.ShouldMap(member) && member.CanWrite;
        }

        public override bool AbstractClassIsLayerSupertype(System.Type type)
        {
            return type == typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>) || type == typeof(Entity);
        }

        public override bool IsId(Member member)
        {
            return member.Name == "Id";
        }
    }
```

The auto-persistence model generator:

```
public class AutoPersistenceModelGenerator : IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator
    {
        public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
        {
            var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Sprint>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
            mappings.IgnoreBase<Entity>();
            mappings.IgnoreBase(typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>));
            mappings.Conventions.Setup(GetConventions());
            mappings.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();

            return mappings;
        }

        private static Action<IConventionFinder> GetConventions()
        {
            return c =>
                   {
                       c.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>();
                       c.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>();
                       c.Add<HasManyConvention>();
                       c.Add<TableNameConvention>();
                   };
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Edit
I figured out that the problem was with the Table Name Convention. Removing that from the AutoMapping configuration solved the problem. I've removed the extraneous code and added the TableNameConvention mapping in the hopes that someone can explain what specifically about it caused those problems.

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(Inflector.Net.Inflector.Pluralize(instance.EntityType.Name));

    }
}
```

Comment: did you check what sql is generated for the id column? where do you apply the id default name?

Answer (score 0):

Your IdGenerator is probably not right. You need to set an appropriate generator for your PrimaryKey. For example, Identity if you're using SQL Server.

I'm not sure how you set this with your setup, not very familiar with Fluent NH. My guess is `PrimaryKeyConvention`?

Comment: Strange thing is, I was debugging this a little further, and I tried specifying the Id generator with HiLo, Identity, and Sequential.  When I specified any one of those, the error disappeared, but now nothing is being added to the database.

Comment: Not flushing the session perhaps? or not committing the transaction?

Comment: I did some more debugging and determined that the problem was with my Table Name Convention. Removing that fixed the problem, or more accurately, bypassed it. I'll have to look into the conventions more to figure out why that happened.